# Timer0 atmega32

Tags: timer, embedded, atmega32

Is TCNT0 set to zero automatically if I stopped the timer (No CLK)?
My  question is about that, if I select that NO CLK using the clock select pins, what will happen to the TCNT0 Register ?

I searched in the datasheet and on the internet but I couldn't  find answer to my question

Comment: What do your experiments reveal? -- If the user manuals do not tell you that TCONT0 is reset, you can assume that it will keep its last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data sheet is rather clear on this:

[image]

"stopped" means exactly what it says - its value will remain unchanged. If it were set to zero by hardware, it would say that.  If it was never in fact started, then its value will be the POR value, which is zero:

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks to you